# Have I done this partial integral correctly?

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate this using partial integration:$$f(x)=x^3 \ln (4x) $$

---

I try:
$$\int{x^3 \ln (4x)} dx$$
$$u = \ln (4x)$$ 
$$dv=x^3 dx$$
$$du=\frac{1}{x} dx$$
$$v = \frac{x^4}{4}$$

$$ \ln (4x)*\frac{x^4}{4}-\int{\frac{x^4}{4}*\frac{1}{x}}dx$$
Answer: $$\ln (4x) *\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^5}{20} \ln{x}$$
Corrects answer: $$\ln (4x) *\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^4}{16}+C$$
Is this correct? 
Sorry for asking these type of questions! I dont have a book! My only source is MathExchange and youtube!

Comment: You can always check your answer by taking the derivative of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. $$\int\frac{x^4}{4}\cdot\frac1x\,dx=\frac14\int x^3\,dx=\frac{x^4}{16}.$$ Also, don't forget about your constant of integration at the end!

Comment: I have updated my questions with the correct answer. Is that alright now? :) Thank you Cameron

Comment: That's it! ${}$

Answer (score 0):

The last integral you did was incorrect. You need to multiply the inside to get $\frac{x^3}{4}$ and then integrate that.